# Error when using System.paths['jquery'] = './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'

Tags: systemjs

I was using traceur and es6 loader, but I change to systemjs and when I try to use System.paths['jquery'], I had the message:

> Error: Cannot set SystemJS.paths["jquery"] directly. Use SystemJS.config({ paths: { "jquery": ... } }) rather

So I change to:

```
System.config({
paths: {
"jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
}    
});
System.import('jquery');
System.import('src/app.js');
```

Show this error:

```
system.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
system.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to dynamically transpile ES module
A loader plugin needs to be configured via `SystemJS.config({ transpiler: 'transpiler-module' })`.
```

I tried, but didn't work:

```
System.config({
transpiler: "babel",
map: {
"babel": "./node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/browser.js",
"jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
}
})
```

Error

```
system.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
Instantiating localhost:3000/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/node
Loading localhost:3000/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/browser.js
Loading babel
Unable to load transpiler to transpile localhost:3000/src/app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to inform systemjs that jquery should be added as a global script so it doesn't try to transpile it. Try the following:

```
System.config({
paths: {
  "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
},
meta: {
  "jquery": { "format": "global" }
}  
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I installed jspm and plugin-babel and create a config file and worked. System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  paths: {
    'babel': 'jspm_packages/npm/systemjs-plugin-babel@0.0.21/plugin-babel.js',
    'systemjs-babel-build': 'jspm_packages/npm/systemjs-plugin-babel@0.0.21/systemjs-babel-browser.js',
    'jquery':'./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'      
  }
});

Comment: I don't know if needs all that, but was a alternative I find.